# Обьект в массиве

Tags: javascript, foreach

у меня возникла такая проблема.у меня есть изображения который я добавляю в массив. и я хочу для каждого изображения в массиве создать  новый  массив с объектом с ссылкой на него и alt, что я делаю не так? в новом массиве должны быть объекты со всеми изображениями.Прошу прощения если плохо объясняю.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
var cache =[];
var arrayImages= [];
var i =0;
var object1 = {};

window.onload = () =>{

    for( var i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
        arrayImages.push(images[i]);
    }
    arrayImages.forEach(function(element){
        cache.push(object1{
            src:element.src,
            text: element.alt,
                })
    })
}
```

Comment: `object1{
            src:element.src,
            text: element.alt,
                }` - вот здесь ошибка, синтаксическая.

Answer (score 0):

оказалась всё намного проще.

```
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
var cache =[];
var arrayImages= [];
var i =0;
var object1 = {};

window.onload = () =>{

    for( var i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
        arrayImages.push(images[i]);
    }
    arrayImages.forEach(function(element){
        cache.push({ // вот тут я удалил object1 и всё заработало.
            src:element.src,
            text: element.alt,
                })
    })
}
```